# Installing a package using SCCM fails with error 0x87D00324(-2016410844) but package is not installed

Tags: sccm, packages, vmware-tools

VMWare Tools are usually installed through SCCM and now the newer version will not be installed through SCCM on all machines. So for some I do have the following failure.

[image]

The error code semes to be straight forward and after some research I found out that it means.. Quote:

> It means that the application is installed successfully, however the
>   software center showing the deployment as failed.
>
> Check the SCCM detection rule => make sure that correct GUID is used
>   in the detection clause

Most of the people fixed this by updating their wrongly setup detection rules. But in our case the detection rule is correct. It checks the file and the version. And the application is **NOT INSTALLED** 
So it's not a detection problem.
Now I wonder what else might be blocking us here. Some servers did get the installation. Others didn't.
The Appenforce log shows that the app was not installed and it is finished after 8-12 seconds.

```
<![LOG[++++++ App enforcement completed (11 seconds) for App DT "VMWare_VMWareTools_10.3.5.10430147"
```

The successfull installation took close to one minute on the other servers, so I guess we get an abortion here or something. Where could I look for more info?

Addtional Info:
I am using SSCM 2012 and my servers are 2016 and 2012, I have failures and success on both versions. So this should not be related.

Anyone had issues like that? 
Any help is upvoted, thank you.

Comment: So as far as I understand it the error just means the software could not be detected which is true from what you say. The reason why people seem to say the detection method might be to blame is probably because if the setup would not return 0 then the error would be different. However if you used a script (vbs, ps1, cmd, ...) and not the msi directly it would probably always return 0 thus making the whole sccm error useless. As SolidSid said best idea would be to enable logging in the setup and check those logs for an error during the setup

Answer (score 3):

Could you post the command line you are using in SCCM to install the software? Also, have you set the install to do any logs? If so, have these been consulted yet?

I've had a similar issue with deploying this application before where the installer falls over if the previous version is running.